# How to install a program that self-downloads from the web, from behind a corporate firewall?

Tags: windows, proxy

I am trying to install [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/) but the installer tries to download files automatically over the internet. This won't work because I'm behind a corporate proxy that blocks some ports and content.

I do have admin rights on my PC, so how can I install this software?

Comment: Use the manual download.

Comment: I think this one is no longer too localised after the edits.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly have you raised this with your support guys, if you've got a proxy you've likely got rules around installing software.  But there should a procedure to follow somewhere.

Two things you can do.
Download composer on your home machine to find out what the extra components are that it requires.  Then find standalone installers for those components and install them first.  i.e. if you've already got all the bits, then it might not need to download them.

Contact the developer see if they can publish/create a full installation package for you.

Comment: +1 for "have you asked the support guys". That is their/our work and they might be very happy to see some person asking a serious question (rather than Halp halp! How do I turn off capslock again?)

Answer (score 1):

Just click the the [Latest Snapshot](http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) link that is on the page you referenced. That has the files that the setup program is downloading.

Comment: I don't know what to do with those files - I'm on Windows not in Linux...

Comment: See [this link explaining phar files](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm). If you are working with PHP (which what composer is for) they likely assume you know what to do with a phar file. (similarly as if if you where working with java and I gave you a jar file)

Comment: I just wanted to install composer as a requirement for a bundle I need to install in Symfony2 framework.. Thanks for the info I will look it up